# Spawn child process as administrator (using child_process)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, child-process

I’m trying to execute .exe file accepting 4 arguments with administrator privileges.

I’ve tried almost everything.
Things like:
`spawn(path_to_cmd_in_sys_32,[path_to_file, arg1,arg2],{detached:true})`
And other combinations of spawn/exec/execFile
But it doesn’t worked.

I’ve also tried to run using runas but I didn’t succeed.

I hope someone can help..
Thank you